# System.linq - GroupBy and Max

Tags: c#, linq

How do I combine groupBy and max?
I want to group by name and get only the latest version.
Something like this

```
Docs.GroupBy(x => x.Name ).Max(x => x.VersionNumber)
```

Is it possible?

the following

```
searchResult.Docs.GroupBy(x => x.PackageName).Select(x => x.Max(x => x.VersionNumber));
```

returns a

```
 IEnumerable<int>
```

and not

```
 IEnumerable<Doc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order each group by version number and select first doc only (it will have max version number):

```
Docs.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.VersionNumber).First())
```

Your code is not working, because you are selecting value of max version number (which is int) instead of selecting doc which has max version number.

Answer (score 0):

You could order it descinding and get the first element of the result, for sample:

```
searchResult.Docs.GroupBy(x => x.PackageName).OrderByDescending(x => x.Max(x => x.VersionNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the latest element of the group the query is:

```
.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(y=>y.OrderbyDescending(z=>z.Version).FirstorDefault());
```